# Cefsharp LoadHtml throwing 'string too long'

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, base64, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have been using loadhtml for some time now and its working fine for the simple thing I was using it for.

However, I recently started including images in my HTML in form of base64 and loadhtml doesn't like that and throughs string too long exception.

From what I understand so far that it's limited to ~2000 which is why it worked fine when the image was very small.

Is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed HTML source in the project and read the project from the dlls into a string buffer.
After that; use loadString method to load the required page.

Answer (score 2):

As for CefSharp Version 75 there are 4 overloads for `LoadHtml` see: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/Overload_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_LoadHtml.htm

Specifically call [`LoadHtml(this IWebBrowser browser, string html, bool base64Encode = false)`](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_LoadHtml_1.htm)
**and base64Encode:true**.

It works even with large HTML